# How do you run Codename One project on terminal?

Tags: codenameone

How do you run Codename One project on terminal? I didn't find any information on the docs.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the project settings you would see that this is what we do in the run section:

```
java -classpath JavaSE.jar:dist/yourJarFile.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.yourpackagename.YourMainClassName
```

Notice that this uses the Mac/Linux path separators of `:`, `/` replace them with `;`, `\` for Windows as such:

```
java -classpath JavaSE.jar;dist\yourJarFile.jar com.codename1.impl.javase.Simulator com.yourpackagename.YourMainClassName
```

Comment: Does Intellij create a jar file when you compile like eclipse does?

Comment: I am trying to run the intellij project from the terminal.

Comment: It should, at least when you send a build to the servers.